# Few doubts about "Apple USB-C Charge Cable (2 m)"

Tags: usb

### Apple USB-C Charge Cable (2 m)

- Is it a Thunderbolt 3 cable?
- Which USB version this cable is using?
- Is it the same cable which comes with new MacBooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a Thunderbolt cable. Although they have the same shape connectors, they are different things. You can tell by the icon on the plug whether a cable is TB or USB.

As for the version, that's more complex. Apple don't specify it on their page. This webpage https://9to5mac.com/2018/08/22/how-to-choose-a-usb-c-cable/ suggests that products called "charge cables" may have low data transfer speeds, and you may be better off getting a quality third-party USB-C cable that can handle USB3.1 SuperSpeed, if that's what you need.

Look for the correct "SuperSpeed" icon on the end of the plug.

It probably is the same cable that comes with a new Mac, but really you'll need to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a Thunderbolt 3 cable?

No.

> Which USB version this cable is using?

USB 2.0.

> Is it the same cable which comes with new MacBooks?

Yes.

The cable is rated for 20 volt power at 5 amps, suitable to connect any Apple iProduct with USB-C charging to a power brick.  Apple calls it a "charge only" cable but it will support USB 2.0 data transfer which should do well enough for small file transfers and such, or as a means to connect a backup drive or something when nothing else is available.

Passive Thunderbolt 3 cables will be less than a meter long, but then so are some low cost "charge only" cables.  If you are looking for a Thunderbolt cable then expect it to be short: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ4H2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb%E2%80%91c-cable-08-m

Or expensive: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/ML8E3AM/A/thunderbolt-3-pro-cable-2-m

Another expensive example: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HMBH2ZM/A/belkin-thunderbolt-3-5a-cable-2-m